# Erro SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: nota_fiscals ao utilizar o Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, migrations

Olá, pessoal.
Este é a minha primeira pergunta aqui, estou começando a programar e me deparei com um erro que não consigo resolver de forma nenhuma. Já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo descobrir o problema. Segue abaixo o erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: nota_fiscals (SQL: insert into "nota_fiscals" ("numNota", "emissao", "valor", "competencia", "idEmpresa", "idSecretaria", "idContrato", "idEmpenho") values (1355, 2022-01-26, 18500, Janeiro, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

Tentei verificar no meu código onde foi criado esta tabela nota_fiscals porém não localizei em lugar nenhum, olhei nas migrations, na classe de controle, nos models, mas não consegui localizar.
Tentei apagar o banco e recriar, usando o **php artisan migrate:fresh** e até mesmo o **migrate:rollback** mas o erro persiste. Vou postar alguns dos meus códigos para que vocês possam analisar e verificar onde possivelmente errei.

**Migration**

```
<?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CriarTabelaNotasFiscais extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('notasFiscais',
                function(Blueprint $table){
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('numNota');
                    $table->string('emissao');
                    $table->float('valor');
                    $table->string('competencia');
                    $table->string('idEmpenho');
                    $table->string('idContrato');
                    $table->string('idEmpresa');
                    $table->string('idSecretaria');
                }
            );
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::drop('notasFiscais');
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\NotaFiscal;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\CriadorDeNotasFiscais;
use App\Http\Requests\NotaFiscalFormRequest;
use App\Models\{Empenho, Contrato, Empresa, Secretaria};

class NotasFiscaisController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Código comentado pois enquanto não tiver nota cadastrada ele apresenta erro
        // $notasFiscais = NotaFiscal::all()->sortBy('competencia');
        // $mensagem = $request->session()->get('mensagem');

        // return view('notas.index', compact('notasFiscais', 'mensagem'));

        return view('notas.index');
    }

    public function create ()
    {
        $empresas = Empresa::query()->orderBy('nome')->get();
        $secretarias = Secretaria::query()->orderBy('nome')->get();
        $contratos = Contrato::query()->orderBy('numContrato')->get();
        $empenhos = Empenho::query()->orderBy('numEmpenho')->get();

        return view('notas.create', compact('empresas', 'secretarias', 'contratos', 'empenhos'));
    }

    public function store(NotaFiscalFormRequest $request, CriadorDeNotasFiscais $criadorDeNotasFiscais)
    {
        $notaFiscal = $criadorDeNotasFiscais->criarNotasFiscais(
            $request->numNota,
            $request->emissao,
            $request->valor,
            $request->competencia,
            $request->idEmpresa,
            $request->idSecretaria,
            $request->idContrato,
            $request->idEmpenho
        );

        $request->session()->flash(
            'mensagem', "Nota Fiscal nº {$notaFiscal->numNota} cadastrado com sucesso!"
        );

        return redirect()->route('listar_notas');
    }

    public function destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

**Classe Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Empresa;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class NotaFiscal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['numNota', 'emissao', 'valor', 'competencia', 'idEmpresa', 'idSecretaria', 'idContrato', 'idEmpenho'];

    public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
    }
}
```

E por fim, segue uma imagem de como estão as tabelas no Banco de Dados sqlite
[image: banco de dados]

Novamente, reforço que estou começando a programar agora, ainda não tenho muitas noções de PHP, HTML ou JS, então peço desculpas se for um erro bobo.
Já agradeço pela atenção de vocês e fico no aguardo de um auxílio

Comment: Dá uma lida nas convenções  de nomes do Laravel

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No seu caso como seu model está em português e a convenção define o nome da tabela baseando-se que o model (nome da classe) está em inglês. Dito isso, o Laravel "automaticamente" entende, por exemplo, que o model NotaFiscal se refere a tabela nota_fiscals ou ainda em outro exemplo um model chamado **MeuCarro** tem a tabela referente **meu_carros** e pra finalizar, um model chamado **User** teria sua tabela referente com o nome **users**.

No seu caso, no model você pode definir o nome da tabela como abaixo ( observe que eu adicionei protected $table = 'notasFiscais'; )

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Empresa;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class NotaFiscal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'notasFiscais';

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['numNota', 'emissao', 'valor', 'competencia', 'idEmpresa', 'idSecretaria', 'idContrato', 'idEmpenho'];

    public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
    }
}
```

Contudo, para seguir melhor a convenção de definição dos nomes das tabelas eu  criaria a migration(nome da tabela) como (snake case) :

```
class CriarTabelaNotasFiscais extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notas_fiscais',
        .......
        .......
```

E no model alteraria

```
protected $table = 'notasFiscais';
```

Para

```
protected $table = 'notas_fiscais';
```

Comment: Marcos, sua solução resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado. Eu não sabia desta convenção de utilizar o underline para separar as palavras, foi onde acabei me enganando, foi só fazer conforme você me recomendou e o programa funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Os down votes não param haha, o SO deveria obrigaar comentar o motivo do down vote :)